# How to pass a dynamic array to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

Please help me to make a dynamic array to my Ajax.

I want to pass a dynamic array to my function appendOption() before appending it to my UI. Please help me. Thanks.

```js
CSVFile.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

      var array0 = [];
      var array1 = [];
      var array2 = [];
      var array3 = [];
      var array4 = [];
      var array5 = [];

 parseCSV.loadFile(file, function () {
      var sheet = parseCSV.getSheet();
      var columnCount;   
      sheet.forEach(function (el, i) {
      columnCount = el.length;

        array0.push(el[0]);
        array1.push(el[1]);
        array2.push(el[2]);
        array3.push(el[3]);
        array4.push(el[4]);
        array5.push(el[5]);

});
      //This is my ajax
      var myRoot = window.location.origin + "/";
        $.ajax({
            url: myRoot + 'Payslip/GetDataFromAppend',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //data: JSON.stringify({ id: $this }),
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    $(wrapper).append(appendOption(data, array0));
                }
            }
          });
          
          
          //This is my function
    //For Append from ajax
    var appendOption = function (data, arrayData) {
        
    var appendfor = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><input type="text" class="form-control"  value="' + arrayData+ '"/></label><div class="col-sm-7">' +
        '<select class="form-control" asp-for="PayslipID" asp- items="ViewBag.PayslipID" data- val="true" data- val - required="The Payslip ID field is required." id= "PayslipID" name= "PayslipID" >';
   
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             console.log(data[i].value);
             appendfor += '<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + 
           data[i].value 
          + '</option>';
           }
           appendfor += '</select ></div ></div > ';
           return appendfor;
       }
     }
    });


 });


 });


//For Append from ajax
var appendOption = function (data, txtData) {
var appendfor = '<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-4 control-label"><input type="text" class="form-control"  value="' + txtData + '"/></label><div class="col-sm-7">' +
    '<select class="form-control" asp-for="PayslipID" asp- items="ViewBag.PayslipID" data- val="true" data- val - required="The Payslip ID field is required." id= "PayslipID" name= "PayslipID" >';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].value);
    appendfor += '<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].value + '</option>';
}
appendfor += '</select ></div ></div > ';
return appendfor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can c that columnCount is undefined.so skiping it.Use java script hoisting. i.e, declare the function on top and then call the function.[https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp] Hope this code snipet is useful.

```js
let ar1 = [1,2,3];
let ar2 = [4,5,8];
let ar3 = [6,7,8];
//use hoisitng  so declare thhe function on top
var appendOption = function (data, arrayData) {
console.log("data is "+data+" array data is "+arrayData)
}
//making mock server data - reprensenting ajax
let data = [1,2,3]
 for (let i in data) {
 appendOption(data[i],ar1[i]); //executes until the lenght of data
 appendOption(data[i],ar2[i]);
 appendOption(data[i],ar2[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Typo appendOption(data[i],ar2[i]); is called twide use appendOption(data[i],ar3[i]); instead